# Using react-navigation 3.* how to navigate from screen to same level BottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I got react native app with such structure:

- ./App.js
- ./screens/AppNavigator.js
- ./screens/SignInScreen.js
- ./screens/HomeScreen.js
- ./screens/FavoritesScreen.js

App.js:

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import AppNavigator from './screens/AppNavigator';
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <AppContainer/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

screens/AppNavigator.js:

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import SignInScreen from './SignInScreen';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import FavoritesScreen from './FavoritesScreen';

const AppBottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({ 
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen
    },
    Favorites: {
        screen: FavoritesScreen
    }
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

export default createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        App: AppBottomTabNavigator,
        Auth: SignInScreen
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'SignInScreen',
    }
);
```

screens/SignInScreen.js:

```
export default class SignInScreen extends React.Component {  
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button title="Continue w/o sing in..." onPress={this.toApp} />
            </View>
        );
    }

    toApp = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('App'); // from here I try to navigate to Home screen
    };
}
```

And when I try to navigate to HomeScreen from SignInScreen I see white screen instead of HomeScreen, though all other navigation works well.

The problem do not occur if in screens/AppNavigator.js I change createBottomTabNavigator to createSwitchNavigator, got no idea why. A problem also do not appear if in screens/AppNavigator.js I navigate direct to HomeScreen or FavoritesScreen instead of AppBottomTabNavigator.
I found [this thread on github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/335), but, as I understand, it's not related for me, because both AppBottomTabNavigator and SignInScreen are childs of AppNavigator.

So, what is weong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in de App.js. For some reason you can't put a BottomTabNavitation inside a View Component, so remove. Like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <AppContainer/>
    );
  }
}
```

You should also change the parameter initialRoutName in createSwitchNavigator. You have to put the routName, in this case Auth.

```
export default createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        App: AppBottomTabNavigator,
        Auth: SignInScreen
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Auth',
    }
);
```